# TAB thru webpage input fields & place mouse cursor at x,y

Tags: powershell

When you're on a webpage, if you repeatedly press the "TAB" key, the webpage input fields successively highlight. My question/problem is:  I can't figure out how to tell Powershell the x,y location of that highlighted input field, so I can move the cursor there.

(Terminology question:  Are those highlighted input fields called "the Focus" of the webpage?)

Note:
I *do* understand how to move the mouse cursor to any x,y location on screen, and I *do* know how to left-click the mouse cursor etc when the cursor is at that x,y location.  (That part's easy).

I want to only use PowerShell to accomplish this task, rather than be forced to learn another tool like VB or AutoIt etc.  It just seems odd to me that the PowerShell folks never thought about writing a cmdlet specifically to solve this simple task...

After months of research I've found nothing to "try", and I think it's pretty clear what I'm expecting.

Comment: This can be done with [browser automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704642/powershell-web-automation) but it's a little complicated to do what you're asking. You would navigate to the page, select the input field with Javascript, and get the X and Y which will be relative to the browser.  There are Windows APIs that can get the X and Y of the cursor or a text box relative to the screen.  It's not clear from your question which coordinates you want, or how/why you plan to move to the x,y location.  Perhaps including the code you've tried would help.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the topic of "Browser Automation".  The more I think about Browser Automation, the more convinced I am you're on the right track.  

A PowerShell solution I had imagined was a script to examine *EVERY PIXEL* on screen, to search for that odd/unique pixel color that outlines an input field when you've tabbed onto it..., but I expect that script would run painfully slowly. Perhaps an equivalent tool built from compiled code would run much faster (but building that is way beyond my skillset at this point).